# Virtualize Kickstart Server

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, docker

I have a cluster of computers and I am using one of them as a [kickstart](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) server. 
I configured DHCP/TFTP/FTP on it and it worked fine. When you boot any box in the cluster and choose to boot from network, it will reach out to that kickstart server, lease an IP, install OS..etc. However, using one box dedicated for kickstart is such a waste of resource and I am wondering is it possible to use some level of virtualization to achieve that, so you end up with a image that is a fully functional ks server and can be running on any box with the virtuallization tool set up?

I have used VirtualBox, Vagrant and Docker before but I am not sure will these tools be powerful enought to do it? Can anyone give some directional guidance or resource to help me get started.

Answer (score 0):

Just virtualize the kickstart server;

Use the virtual environment DHCP Server facility and set the Kickstart Server DHCP module as "proxyDHCP"

When a PXE client boots up will get its IP from the virtual environment DHCP Server and the PXE booting information from the instance of the kickstart proxyDHCP server.
Next the PXE client will know where the TFTP and the rest of the kickstart facilities are located and will continue the boot/install.

Answer (score 0):

Yep I always run kickstart on a VM, A good way to do things is have a bunch of VM's and share them across hosts. Pretty much every site I build out I have the following VM's

Build: running Kickstart/Cobbler, DHCP, TFTP
Provision: running Puppet or Chef
Monitoring: Zenoss or Nagios

The VM's disks all live on iscsi and create the VM's with libvirt KVM. Everything can easily live on one server. I usually have a second server that is prepared for the VM's and if there is ever an outage I just bring them up on the second server.